# Поля объекта становятся кортежами вместо строк

Tags: python

Есть следующий класс

```
class Drive(object):
    def __init__(self, key, manufacturer, model, kind, size, interface, ff, price):
        self.key = key
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer,
        self.model = model,
        self.kind = kind,
        self.size = size,
        self.interface = interface,
        self.ff = ff,
        self.price = price
```

Часть переменных для инициализации перед созданием экземпляра класса вычисляются с использованием функции `re.sub()`. После их передачи конструктору класса соответствующие поля представляются кортежами, а не строками. Почему так?
Неужели мне нужно явно преобразовывать каждую переменную через `str()`?

При этом, если инициализировать поля вне конструктора (после создания объекта), то они будут строками.

Comment: Нужен пример вызова конструктора. Или у Вас там где-то скобки лишние (литерал кортежа), либо `re.subn` вместо `re.sub`

Comment: `disk = Drive(key, manufacturer, model, kind, size, interface, ff, price)`

Comment: Не то, нужно понять как делаются `key` и т.д. перед вызовом конструктора. Ну не может питон сам строку в кортеж перевести. Добавьте в вопрос строчку кода с вычислением некорректного параметра.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ОМГ, слона то я и не заметил.
Зачем запятые после присваивания?!

```
self.kind = kind,
```

выполните в консоли питона

```
x = 'xxx',
```

и посмотрите, что записалось в `x`
Все дело в том, что `kind,` - по сути такой же литерал кортежа, как и `(kind,)`

Уберите запятые:

```
self.kind = kind
```

и будет Вам счастье)